# @RabbitListener annotation over class

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq

I have a spring-boot based application. I'm trying to create a multi-method Rabbit listener with reference to [Multi-method Listeners](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/#annotation-method-selection)

My old version works:

```
@Service
public class ListenEvents {

   public ListenEvents() {
   }

   @RabbitListener(queues = "#{queue.name}")
   void create(@Payload Created created) {
        //SOME ACTIONS
   }

   @RabbitListener(queues = "#{queue.name}")
   void update(@Payload Updated updated) {
       //SOME ACTIONS
   }
}
```

But new one does not:

```
@Service
@RabbitListener(queues = "#{queue.name}")
public class ListenEvents {

    public ListenEvents() {
    }

    @RabbitHandler
    void create(@Payload Created created) {
            //SOME ACTIONS
    }

    @RabbitHandler
    void update(@Payload Updated updated) {
            //SOME ACTIONS
    }
}
```

with stack:

```
2021-03-31 10:58:31.047  WARN 99872 --- [ntContainer#0-1] s.a.r.l.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler : Execution of Rabbit message listener failed.

org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method 'no match' threw exception
    
...

Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpException: No method found for class java.util.LinkedHashMap
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.DelegatingInvocableHandler.getHandlerForPayload(DelegatingInvocableHandler.java:149) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.DelegatingInvocableHandler.invoke(DelegatingInvocableHandler.java:129) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.HandlerAdapter.invoke(HandlerAdapter.java:61) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:211) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
```

Does anyone have an idea how to fix the second solution?

Edit:
Just to clarify:

*Jackson2JsonMessageConverter* is used as a *MessageConverter*

Payload classes:

```
public final class Created {

    private final Data data;

    public Created(@JsonProperty(value = "created") Data data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Data data() {
        return data;
    }
}

    
public final class Updated {

    private final Data data;

    public Updated(@JsonProperty(value = "updated") Data data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Data data() {
        return data;
    }
}


public final class Data {

    private final String value;

    public UserData(
      @JsonProperty(value = "value", required = true) String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String value() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Make your methods `public` instead of default access modifiers.

Comment: it does not change anything